# Google Colab cells still running after various crashes occured

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to make prediction for a deep learning example but I am running into repetitive issues.

In some cases the browser becomes "unresponcive" and I am inclined to leave the page, which results in all outputs of the cells disappearing, but the cell being executed continues to execute.

In another case all of my chrome browsers crash... when I then return to my notebook it enters a runtime state of "busy" where gain the cell is apparently executing and yet again I see no outputs.

Now if there was a way to go around this that would be great however I doubt it. What I really want to know is: is my code really still being executed? In other words will the prediction of my code still find themselves in my target folders?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a self-contained notebook that reproduces this state?

Comment: Sorry what does a self-contained notebook mean? Sadly I am not permitted to share my code, nevertheless code snippets are allowed. So I'll take it this is an unusual case? (could not find anything online)